# Why redefining a structure with same name, contain values of the 1st structure, even if the 2nd structure is declared after the first is destroyed?

Tags: c, struct, scope

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    int a;
    int b;
}my_struct;

void check (my_struct *my_check)
{
    printf ("%d\n", my_check->a);
}

int main()
{
  //block with local variables
    {
    int a = 2;
    printf("int inside block %d\n", a);
    my_struct m1;
    m1.a = 2;
    printf ("my_struct m1 inside block\t");
    check (&m1);
    }
    
//outside the block; so the variables and their values inside the above block is outside the scope of the following code
    int a;
    printf("int outside block %d\n", a);
    my_struct m2;
    my_struct m1;
    printf ("my_struct m1 outside block\t");
    check (&m1);
    printf ("my_struct m2 outside block\t");
    check(&m2);
    
    return 0;
}
```

The above piece of code will output

```
int inside block 2 
my_struct m1 inside block 2
int outside block 0
my_struct m1 outside block 2
my_struct m2 outside block 522062864
```

My question is:

1. Why "int a" inside the block was not accessible with a variable of same name i.e. int a, but "my_struct m1" was?

My understanding is, if it is outside the block, then it is fresh declaration and definition. New assignment is needed for variables outside, else they will contain default/garbage values

Comment: Because the struct has the same name, could be referencing the same memory location. In your case this means the same value, but I would wager this is far from guaranteed. What you are getting (the 2) is essentially garbage values, but in this simple example it happens to correspond to the same value. Someone more knowledgeable would need to confirm, this is just a hunch.

Comment: @Manish The question does not make a great sense because the program can output whatever was stored in the memory that will be occupied by a new object.

Comment: They are different variables. The "local" one is destroyed, thus the same place could be used by another one.

Comment: Because they're at the same address on the stack. This is undefined behavior though, and the value of the second one can't be relied upon because it's not initialized.

Comment: You use uninitialized local variables, their values will be *indeterminate* (and you should really look at their values being ***garbage***). You could run into *undefined behavior* this way.

Comment: Even if I initialise to something else, e.g m1.a inside the block to say 1947, the m1.a outside the block also prints same 1947. Tried in multiple online compilers. Same result. Is it just a coincidence that m1 outside the block is going and occupying the same address?

Even if I uninitialize the m1 inside the struct, both m1.a print same garbage value every time

Answer (score 1):

You are in the world of Undefined Behaviour. You have created some variables in the *inside* block. Fine. Then when you exit the block, those variables vanish. You now create **different** variables in the *outside*. And you try to use those uninitialized variables which is explicitely Undefined Behaviour.

That means that what happens could be different from one system to another one, or on the same system with different compilation options, or even on different runs. And anyway, you should never rely on that consistently happening.

Now what actually happens **in that system and in that specific run**: your implementation probably uses the stack for the structures and registers for single values for which you never use an address. So when you create a new single variable it receives what was in a register and could be anything. But when you create a new struct it just reuses the memory that has just be released by the previous one, and you get the old value. But as I have already said you cannot rely on that.